# How to set a value in a row, using sum function on mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a `trigger` for my `mysql` database, what i want to create is if sum of two columns is bigger than `2,5` set a some column value U else set a value of A.

I tried something like,

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Ust` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `Fransa` 
FOR EACH ROW 
  if SUM(J+K) > 2,5 
    set R = 'U' 
  else 
    R = 'A' 
end;
```

But it doesn't work, i get this message,

> MySQL meldt: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '5 set R = 'U' else R='A' end' at line 1

if somebody can help be i will be very happy, thank you all.

Comment: Does this need to be a trigger?

Comment: I don't know what i want to achieve is, if a put manually values in to J and K column that R column automatic will be filled with one of the two values (U or A), something like formules in excel.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand why you need to store derived data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss `set`?

```
DELIMITER $$

  CREATE TRIGGER `Ust` 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `Fransa` 
  FOR EACH ROW begin
    if (OLD.J + OLD.K) > 2.5 Then
      set NEW.R = 'U' ;
    else 
      set NEW.R = 'A' ;
    end if;
  end$$

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: @user3360123 try now.

Comment: This is now what happend. Any idea ? Thank you. MySQL meldt: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ CREATE TRIGGER `Ust` BEFORE UPDATE ON `Fransa` FOR EACH ROW begi' at line 1

Comment: @user3360123 try now

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i really appreciate it, may be i have to mention something, i tried to create this trigger using phpmyadmin. Make it sense ?